# Efficient way to store and process large amounts of data in Huggingface

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, huggingface, huggingface-datasets

I need to create about 200 pretty large dictionaries, that if converted to a Huggingface dataset, each weights about 10Gb. I'm trying to find an efficient way to store them and process them in a training script.

The naive approach would be to just save each as a huggingface dataset, which will be easy to load, but that will result in about 2Tb of space which is more than my machine can handle.

Another approach would be to save each dictionary as a pickle file, which weights about 500Mb each, which is doable on my machine. But, from [here](https://huggingface.co/docs/hub/security-pickle) it seems like huggingface is discouraging pickle files and I haven't found an efficient way to load them.

Saving each as json file results in each weighting more then 30Gb, which again, is not doable on my machine.